# Can JavaScript or jQuery sort a JSON array on multiple criteria?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

I have a JSON array of potential results for an autocomplete list.

The list is defined as:

```
var fundList = [ //there's lots more than this
    { "name": "Pension Managed Fund 1" },
    { "name": "Managed Property Fund 2" },
    { "name": "Retirement Managed Fund 3" },
    { "name": "Retirement Managed Fund 4" }
]
```

I need to sort the list alphabetically, but it has to also be ordered by the relevance to the value entered into textbox (which triggers the automcomplete)

So for example, if the user types "Managed" into the textbox, the list above would be sorted as follows:

```
Managed Property Fund 2

Pension Managed Fund 1

Retirement Managed Fund 3

Retirement Managed Fund 4
```

If they typed "Retirement", the list would be sorted:

```
Retirement Managed Fund 3

Retirement Managed Fund 4

Managed Property Fund 2

Pension Managed Fund 1
```

If "Fund" was typed, the order would be normal alphabetical order:

```
Managed Property Fund 2

Pension Managed Fund 1

Retirement Managed Fund 3

Retirement Managed Fund 4
```

Is there any in-built functionality in JavaScript or jQuery which will do this?

Comment: Side note: Once it gets decoded, it's no longer JSON.

Answer (score 1):

javascript has an array sort method that can take a function as a parameter this will allow you to define how you want things sorted

for example

```
var fundList = [ //there's lots more than this
    { "name": "Pension Managed Fund 1" },
    { "name": "Managed Property Fund 2" },
    { "name": "Retirement Managed Fund 3" },
    { "name": "Retirement Managed Fund 4" }
]

funcList.sort(function(a, b){
 if (a == b)
 {
   return 0;
 }

 if (SOME CRITERIA TO SORT a AT A LOWER INDEX THEN b)
 {
   return -1;
 }

 if (SOME CRITERIA TO SORT b AT A LOWER INDEX THEN a)
 {
    return 1;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) can take a function as a comparator; I guess you need to sort every string containing a search term ahead of every string without it, and break ties alphabetically:

```
var query = 'Managed';
fundList.sort(function(a, b)
{
    var match_a = a.name.indexOf(query) >= 0;
    var match_b = b.name.indexOf(query) >= 0;
    if(match_a && !match_b)
        return -1;
    if(!match_a && match_b)
        return 1;
    if(a.name < b.name)
        return -1;
    if(a.name > b.name)
        return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Use this as a starting point; instead of [String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to work out if a string matches the query I'd at the very least ignore case and spacing.

Comment: Hi Andrew, this looks useful but I'm unsure what the parameters `a` & `b` are. Just trying the code here, and both are 'undefined'. I see your point though about using indexOf. I'll try to use a regex for that.

Comment: I had my brain in the wrong mode; without "new " before "function" it should work better. `a` and `b` are two elements in the array that `sort` wants you to determine the order of.

Comment: I also just noticed that your array has objects with name properties rather than strings, so I fixed that too.