# How can I sort this JavaScript object based on the name and then order by relevance?

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I asked the following question earlier: [Can JavaScript or jQuery sort a JSON array on multiple criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160263/can-javascript-or-jquery-sort-a-json-array-on-multiple-criteria/)

I think I may have made a mistake in asking the question because I specified a JavaScript array, rather than an object, and it appears that this difference is the source of the difficulty I'm experiencing.

I have the following object defined by JSON that exists on my page, which is used for a AutoComplete functionality:

```
var fundList = [
    { "name": "Pension Managed Fund 1", "id": 21, "cid": "N0", "dupId": 53 },
    { "name": "Managed Property Fund 2", "id": 407, "cid": "N0", "dupId": 58 },
    { "name": "Retirement Managed Fund 3", "id": 640, "cid": "N0", "dupId": 111 },
    { "name": "Retirement Managed Fund 4", "id": 752, "cid": "N0", "dupId": 115 }
]
```

I need to sort these items alphabetically based on their names, but they also have to be ordered by the relevance to the value entered into a textbox (which triggers the automcomplete)

So for example, if the user types "Managed" into the textbox, the list above would be sorted as follows:

```
Managed Property Fund 2

Pension Managed Fund 1

Retirement Managed Fund 3

Retirement Managed Fund 4
```

If they typed "Retirement", the list would be sorted:

```
Retirement Managed Fund 3

Retirement Managed Fund 4

Managed Property Fund 2

Pension Managed Fund 1
```

If "Fund" was typed, the order would be normal alphabetical order:

```
Managed Property Fund 2

Pension Managed Fund 1

Retirement Managed Fund 3

Retirement Managed Fund 4
```

What do I need to do to be able to sort this based on the name and the criteria I specified? I've tried to use `fundList.sort(new function(a, b)` as suggested in the previous question, but that returns a function undefined error.

Comment: [This](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) didn't work?

Comment: Hi sternr, no. as per `fundList.sort(new function(a, b) ` that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously read up on [how to sort arrays](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml) in javascript.

Here's one way to do it:

```
var fundList = [
        { "name": "Pension Managed Fund 1", "id": 21, "cid": "N0", "dupId": 53 },
        { "name": "Managed Property Fund 2", "id": 407, "cid": "N0", "dupId": 58 },
        { "name": "Retirement Managed Fund 3", "id": 640, "cid": "N0", "dupId": 111 },
        { "name": "Retirement Managed Fund 4", "id": 752, "cid": "N0", "dupId": 115 }
    ],
    textEntered = 'Managed';

fundList.sort(function(a, b)
{
    var aStart = a.name.match(new RegExp('^'+textEntered, 'i')) || [],
        bStart = b.name.match(new RegExp('^'+textEntered, 'i')) || [];

    if ( aStart.length != bStart.length ) return bStart.length - aStart.length;

    else return a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/txJVB/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
var fundList = [
        { "name": "Pension Managed Fund 1", "id": 21, "cid": "N0", "dupId": 53 },
        { "name": "Managed Property Fund 2", "id": 407, "cid": "N0", "dupId": 58 },
        { "name": "Retirement Managed Fund 3", "id": 640, "cid": "N0", "dupId": 111 },
        { "name": "Retirement Managed Fund 4", "id": 752, "cid": "N0", "dupId": 115 }
    ],
    textEntered = 'Managed';

fundList.sort(function(a, b)
{
    ai = a.name.indexOf(textEntered);
    bi = b.name.indexOf(textEntered);
    if(ai>=0 && bi<0) return -1;
    else if(bi>=0 && ai<0) return 1;
    else return a.name - b.name;
});
```

Comment: If both of the compared items have the matching string, the last else won't work as expected. Shouldn't it be `else return ai - bi`?